# Kendo AutoComplete - suggest choices before the user types anything

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo AutoComplete textbox (as an Editor Template within a Grid, if it matters) and it will only suggest choices if the user types something into it.

This makes it reasonably difficult to see the entire list of choices since if you start typing to make the suggestion list appear, the list it shows will be filtered with what you typed. You need to backspace over what you typed to see all the available options.

Is there a way to see the suggestion list as soon as the control receives focus?

Comment: Here is a forum entry that may help.  http://www.telerik.com/forums/display-all-possibilities-in-dropdown#2346029

Comment: Seems to me like you're using the wrong UI component for the job. Have you considered a [combobox](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/index) instead of an autocomplete?

Comment: Thanks Brett, a combo box did the trick. Feel free to write an answer and I will accept it.